# Find out if class field annotated by Gson SerializedName actually existes in Json

Tags: java, json, parsing, serialization, gson

I'm using google Gson to parse json and create an appropriate object:

```
public class Settings {
    @SerializedName("version")
    public String version = "1";

    @SerializedName("ad_native_enabled")
    public boolean nativeAdEnabled = false;
}
```

The problem is that I need to know if the value of  `nativeAdEnabled` is actually parsed from json or it's the default value specified by me, i.e.  does the `ad_native_enabled` key exist in json, or not? I've tried to use **Boolean** instead of **boolean** and just do null check, but Gson deserialisation failed. Here is the snippet of my json:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "ad_native_enabled": false,
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**

*In my situation it's not relevant and elegant to parse the json by hand and do the detection on that level(and I guess in this case I have to priorly owe the list of the keys the existence  of which I want to check). It's highly desirable to somehow infer the needed information on the object level.*

I described a problem on the example of a boolean, but the question may be generalised and may refer to all primitive types. So it'd be great to have a generic solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you already tried this, but using a `Boolean` field should work. I have reduced your example down a bit, and it works as expected.

I defined the `Settings` class like this:

```
public static class Settings {
    @SerializedName("ad_native_enabled")
    public Boolean nativeAdEnabled;
}
```

If you then parse JSON that contains the field:

```
String json = "{\"ad_native_enabled\": false}";
Settings settings = gson.fromJson(json, Settings.class);
System.out.println(settings.nativeAdEnabled);  // prints false
```

Whereas if you parse JSON that does not contain the field:

```
String emptyJson = "{}";
Settings emptySettings = gson.fromJson(emptyJson, Settings.class);
System.out.println(emptySettings.nativeAdEnabled);  // prints null
```

Did you perhaps leave the default value of the field as `false`? If so, the second example will print `false` as well. Also it seems GSON does not particularly like trailing commas after the last property in JSON objects - maybe that was why you were getting errors?

---

After seeing your comment, I thought a bit more about whether it is possible to somehow support default values, while still being able to tell whether the field was present in the JSON or not. The best solution I could come up with was to introduce a new wrapper type, with a custom deserializer.

I started by defining this wrapper type, which just contains the actual value of the field, and an indicator of whether this value is the default value or not:

```
public static class ValueWrapper<T> {
    public final T value;
    public final boolean isDefaultValue;

    public ValueWrapper(T value, boolean isDefaultValue) {
        this.value = value;
        this.isDefaultValue = isDefaultValue;
    }
}
```

The `Settings` class then looks like this:

```
public static class Settings {
    @SerializedName("ad_native_enabled")
    public ValueWrapper<Boolean> nativeAdEnabled = new ValueWrapper<>(false, true);
}
```

Here I have defined the field as having value `false` by default, which is why `isDefaultValue` is set to `true`.

I then defined a custom deserializer for this type. The basic idea is to take the type of `ValueWrapper` you are trying to deserialize, extract its generic parameter, deserialize the actual value in the JSON as the generic parameter type, and then return a new `ValueWrapper` where `isDefaultValue` is set to `false`. This deserializer looks like this:

```
public static class ValueWrapperDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ValueWrapper<?>> {
    @Override
    public ValueWrapper<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) typeOfT;
        Type valueType = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Object value = context.deserialize(json, valueType);
        return new ValueWrapper<>(value, false);
    }
}
```

Now all we need to do is register the custom deserializer:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(ValueWrapper.class, new ValueWrapperDeserializer())
            .create();
```

And we can then run through my two examples from above:

```
String json = "{\"ad_native_enabled\": false}";
Settings settings = gson.fromJson(json, Settings.class);
System.out.println(settings.nativeAdEnabled.value);  // prints false
System.out.println(settings.nativeAdEnabled.isDefaultValue);  // prints false

String emptyJson = "{}";
Settings emptySettings = gson.fromJson(emptyJson, Settings.class);
System.out.println(emptySettings.nativeAdEnabled.value);  // prints false
System.out.println(emptySettings.nativeAdEnabled.isDefaultValue);  //prints true
```

So this allows us to have the default value, but still be able to tell whether the field was set or not using `isDefaultValue`. This obviously has quite an impact on the API to the user of the `Settings` object, but perhaps this is neater than handling nulls and storing the default values elsewhere.

Comment: It turned out that Gson lib I was using was obsolete and customised. After updating the lib the method you've described stared to work. One of the drawbacks of this workaround is that I can't have default values, or I must somehow keep a  map of fields to possible default values, and in case of field being null take the value from the map.

Comment: I was pondering about something like this:), I even messed around with JsonDeserializer, but for some unknown reason in my version of Gson registerTypeAdapter failed. So after updating Gson I went further and decided to do some magic with TypeAdapter instead of JsonDeserializer, but the thought of overkill didn't let me to continue:) anyway, I'm accepting your answer!

Comment: Hi, I'm encountering a weird behaviour, in case if deserialisation fails for my Settings class due to some type conversion issue ( java.lang.Exception: Unable to deserialize class com.socialin.android.apiv3.model.Settings  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 1659) I find all my Booleans set to false, but I expect them to be null in that case, can you have any clue?